# Hive move & restore some partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, export, hdfs, metadata

I have a 50TB managed partitioned (by date) Hive table, from which I want to move some old partitions to an external HDD, in order to restore them back later if required.

The scripts are as follows:

Move out:

```
$ hdfs dfs -get ${HIVE_WAREHOUSE_TABLE_PATH}/ingest_date=2016-01-01 ${LOCAL_TABLE_PATH}/2016-01-01
$ hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash ${HIVE_WAREHOUSE_TABLE_PATH}/ingest_date=2016-01-01
$ hive -e "ALTER TABLE ${TABLE} DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (ingestion_date='2016-01-01') PURGE;"
```

Restore:

```
$ hdfs dfs -put ${LOCAL_TABLE_PATH}/2016-01-01 ${HIVE_WAREHOUSE_TABLE_PATH}/ingest_date=2016-01-01
$ hive -e "ALTER TABLE ${TABLE} ADD PARTITION (ingest_date='2016-01-01') LOCATION ${HIVE_WAREHOUSE_TABLE_PATH}/ingest_date=2016-01-01;"
```

Do I miss something in the above strategy?

I have tried:

`$ hive --hivevar local_path=${LOCAL_TABLE_PATH} -e "EXPORT TABLE myDatabase.theTable PARTITION (ingest_date='2016-01-01') to '${local_path}/2016-01-01';"`

but this takes too long to CopyTable for 1 year partitions, and I am trying to avoid this.

Thank you,
Gee

Comment: The HIVE metastore is still aware of the partition `ingest_date=2016-01-01` so I'm not sure what's the impact. I would rather DROP the partition (which will delete the files on HDFS) and recreate it manually on restore

Comment: Thanks @Harold. I edited OP according to your comment

Comment: Looks good. Just use `-rm -skipTrash` to free space immediately

Comment: Thanks. However: "ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION" doesn't remove the HDFS files as well? Step 2 seems not required. In any case, make an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: correct. No need for a rm